# NHibernate INNER JOIN on a SubQuery

Tags: mysql, sql, nhibernate

I would like to do a subquery and then inner join the result of that to produce a query.  I want to do this as I have tested an inner join query and it seems to be far more performant on MySql when compared to a straight IN subquery.

Below is a very basic example of the type of sql I am trying to reproduce.

### *Tables*

**ITEM**

- ItemId
- Name

**ITEMRELATIONS**

- ItemId
- RelationId

### *Example Sql I would Like to create*

Give me the COUNT of RELATIONs for ITEMs having a name of 'bob':

```
select ir.itemId, count(ir.relationId)
  from ItemRelations ir
    inner join (select itemId from Items where name = 'bob') sq
    on ir.itemId = sq.itemId
  group by ir.itemId
```

### *The base Nhibernate QueryOver*

```
var bobItems = QueryOver.Of<Item>(() => itemAlias)
  .Where(() => itemAlias.Name == "bob")
  .Select(Projections.Id());

var bobRelationCount = session.QueryOver<ItemRelation>(() => itemRelationAlias)
   .Inner.Join(/* Somehow join the detached criteria here on the itemId */)
   .SelectList(
      list =>
        list.SelectGroup(() => itemRelationAlias.ItemId)
          .WithAlias(() => itemRelationCountAlias.ItemId)
        .SelectCount(() => itemRelationAlias.ItemRelationId)
          .WithAlias(() => itemRelationCountAlias.Count))
   .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<ItemRelationCount>())
   .List<ItemRelationCount>();
```

I know it may be possible to refactor this into a single query, however the above is merely as simple example.  I cannot change the detached QueryOver, as it is handed to my bit of code and is used in other parts of the system.

Does anyone know if it is possible to do an inner join on a detached criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql 5.6.5 has addressed the performance issue related to the query structure.

See here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42259

No need for me to change the output format of my NHibernate queries anymore.  :)